# how to create an application for windows phone 7 as a service?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to develop an application with windows phone which, works in the background like a service. I need an emergency SMS sender which can be received by the same application in receiver phone. Because it must receive the messages whenever it gets, so it should be a service not a running application, does it work with windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly like that. You can run a Scheduled background agent but it is very limited (also has an expiry date) and can not launch the application. To receive a message you can use notification but again the user has to click somewhere to open the app. You can not send sms automatically without the user pressing send.

I'd suggest re-thinking how you want to build this app. You'll certainly need a back-end service somewhere to which the agent from a phone might send a request to send sms.

Comment: how a bout if I have an application which be online? Does it work or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot install an application on Windows Phone that will act as a service on a standard Windows machine.
2. You can use [push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx) to deliver messages between applications. Background agents will not work well for your scenario, where a message should be delivered almost instantly. However, remember that even with push, there might be a certain delivery lag.
3. There is no way you can send SMS messages without the user's consent in a sandboxed Windows Phone application.
4. You could use services such as [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) to send SMS messages through a commercial backend.